# Quickhull 3D Explained

Tags: algorithm, 3d, convex-hull, qhull

I'm trying to understand how quickhull works in 3D. I already understand how the algorithm works in 2D but I just don't get how the algorithm can be implemented in 3D space. Are there any tutorials or papers that can help me?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it is possible by projecting points in 3D to 2D planes (XY, YZ, XZ), computing convex-hull in 2D and then combining the results.

Comment: I implemented it 20 years ago following the Bradford Barber's paper "The Quick Hull Algorithm for Convex Hulls"  https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ungor/courses/fall06/papers/QuickHull.pdf and it was straightforward, basically you construct the hull iteratively as a 3D mesh departing from a single thetrahedron by classifying the points as outside/inside the hull and tracking them in lists.

Comment: There is very nice tutoriel from Dirk Gregorius, that covers the 3D implementation of Quickhull, available here: https://archive.org/details/GDC2014Gregorius